# Dynamically change div content and script using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am building webpage dashboard example where contents in two divs should be changing depending on selected business process. My example page is [here](http://monitorius.verslomonitorius.lt).

Division on the left shows content of particular html pages with KPI's of selected business process (Supply, Manufacture, Warehouse etc.).

Division on the right contains chat-widget which I want to be individual for every business process (Supply-chat for supply team, Finance-chat for finance team etc.).

Leftside division html content is changing ok, yet with the rightside division content changes there are some problems. Initially it loads Finance chat. When selecting "Supply" chatbox dissappears. Note: changing content (html and chats) are created only for two business areas - Finance and Supply.

The code for changing chat-widget is:

```
function SetChatSupply() {
var divObject = document.getElementById('div_right');
var newContent = '<div id="chatwee_supply"></div>';
divObject.innerHTML = newContent;
};
function SetChatFinance() {
var divObject = document.getElementById('div_right');
var newContent = '<div id="chatwee_finance"></div>';
divObject.innerHTML = newContent;
};
function SetScriptSupply () {
var body = document.getElementByTagName('body')[0];
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.src = 'http://repository.chatwee.com/scripts/069673da978e699031ff2031b4664ff2.js';
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.charset='UTF-8';
body.parentNode.appendChild(newScript);
};
function SetScriptFinance () {
var body = document.getElementByTagName('body')[0];
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.src = 'http://repository.chatwee.com/scripts/6cc6797833fd98149c6e39d505b57ac2.js';
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.charset='UTF-8';
body.parentNode.appendChild(newScript);
};
```

Could someone take a short look at my code and give some clues about what should I correct in it to make chat-widgets changes work..?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Well, for the start - correct method name is `getElementsByTagName` (note plural for Elements)

Comment: Thank you, Ilya. I have changed to plural. The problem persists :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in incorrect method you're using to get body element. Should be like this:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
```

Note the plural form of `Elements` word. And I suggest you to use:

```
var body = document.body;
```

#### UPDATE1:

Another thing should be corrected - you're adding scripts to `html` tag, but this won't work, since scripts are allowed only in `body` and `head` sections. So another thing to try:

```
body.appendChild(newScript);
```

But in fact there is no need of adding your scripts each time the button is clicked. Why don't you just load scripts when your site loads and on click you'd just call functions from that scripts?

#### UPDATE2:

Ok, given the requirement that we can't change the script, I'd suggest this a bit ugly solution (not sure if it'll work though):

```
function SetChatSupply() {
    var divObject = document.getElementById('div_right');
    var newContent = document.createElement('div');
    newContent.setAttribute('id', 'chatwee_supply');
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.src =  'http://repository.chatwee.com/scripts/069673da978e699031ff2031b4664ff2.js';
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newScript.charset='UTF-8';
    divObject.appendChild(newContent);
    divObject.appendChild(newScript);
};
```

So the idea is to combine both of your methods (add `div` and add `script`) in one (function `SetScriptSupply` is not needed anymore), so each time the link is pressed, you overwrite the whole content of `div_right`, the script is reloaded and executed. You should do the same for `finance` chat.

Comment: What's in the `069673da978e699031ff2031b4664ff2.js` script? Your script is obfuscated/minified? I can't find function `SetChatSupply()` in it

Comment: I use chatbox-widget from Chatwee.com, which provides with this .js to make widget work

Comment: There are two such .js files: one for Finance team chatbox, other - for Supply team chatbox.

Comment: I have a flight to catch, will be back later. Can you check that your functions are called on click at all?

Comment: Yes, functions are definitely called. You can look at full code at my [webpage](http://monitorius.verslomonitorius.lt).

Comment: Thank you, Ilya. The thing is that on page load that external script is executed automatically. Script modifies contents of division 'div_right', especially they modify div 'chat_finance' making/loading chatbox in it. And after that when chat users make actions in chat many funcions are called from this script. I don't have access to this sript, it is generated by Chatwee and stored at their servers (SaaS).

Comment: What I want to do is to load different chat, for example Supply chat instead of Finance chat. Therefore I need to change div id from "chatwee_finance" to "chatwee_supply", then stop running one external script (..b57ac2.js file) and load/execute other external script (..664ff2.js file).

Comment: When I load both external .js files in page initially, the last of them creates chat in specified div. When I change id of this div (to  make load another chatbox in it) then initial chatbox dissappears and nothing happens because (I suppose) both scripts already made their initial run on page load and they don't modify the specified div to create another chatbox. Scripts are running just to execute user actions in the chatbox.

Comment: @ValdasVėgėlė, I've updated my answer, please try this in your application.

Comment: Tried, doesn't work. After clicking link and executing new funcion (SetSupply) there is no script added, yet there is row with text "undefined" after division chatwee_supply in division div_right. Maybe it would be better to add script outside the division div_right..?

Comment: Tried to add script at the bottom of body (with modified function SetSupply1). Script is added, yet it is not executed (chatbox not loaded).

Comment: @ValdasVėgėlė, `undefined` was because of incorrect property name (`outerHTML`). Anyway, that solution didn't work, so I updated my answer to use `appendChild` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: There is some progress. I have modified function to remove previous div "chatwee_finance". Function didn't work, yet if I click link before initial page finishes to load the chatbox appears. If I wait until page loads then script doesn't run, yet it is added.

Comment: So, you need to clear `div_right` before appending childs? Try `divObject.innerHTML = '';` right after `var divObject = ...`.

Comment: Content of div_right changes as I want, yet the chat doesn't load. As I have mentioned before, here is some trick: when I click on a link before page finishes initial loading then the chat appears. Yet after that trick, clicking links does nothing, - only code changes and chat doesn't appear. Any clues how to fix this..?

Comment: I have modified the code. Now initially loads the Finance chat and then clicking on links "Supply" or "Finance" just removes the chat and changes div_right contents, yet chat doesn't appear anymore.